# Increase / Decrtease / Delete Persistent volume of appendonly.aof

Tags: redis, poc

I am doing a POC on appendonly.aof
There my requiremt is "How can I crease / Decrtease / Delete Persistent volume of appendonly.aof" I didn't found any proper solution. And I am not using Docker or Docker compose for this.

I am unable to increase the volume.